# asp.net core web api attribute routing: how to specify custom name or short name for controller

Tags: routes, asp.net-core-webapi

My controller looks like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DnsCommonValidationsController : ControllerBase
{
     ;
}
```

With the above setup, my route will look like `"api/dnscommonvalidations"`.

I want to specify a short name to the controller for the purposes of routing. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `Route` attribute like below:

```
[Route("api/Dns")]
[ApiController]
public class DnsCommonValidationsController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

Then you could send request by using the url: `api/dns`.

Reference:[Attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0#attribute-routing)